# extract html element attributes

Tags: html, vb.net, visual-studio-2008

I am newbie to VB 2008.net , what I want to do is to extract some elements from the below html

```
<TABLE>
  <TR>
    <TD></TD>
    <TH scope="col">PAT. NO.</TH><TD></TD><TH scope="col">Title</TH>
  </TR>
  <TR>
    <TD valign=top>
      10
    </TD>
    <TD valign=top>
      <A  HREF=/netacgi/nph-Parser?Sect1=PTO2&Sect2=HITOFF&u=%2Fnetahtml%2FPTO%2Fsearch-adv.htm&r=10&p=1&f=G&l=50&d=PTXT&S1=*a&OS=*a&RS=*a>8,519,110</A>
    </TD>
    <TD valign=baseline>
      <IMG border=0 src="/netaicon/PTO/ftext.gif" alt="Full-Text">
    </TD>
    <TD valign=top>
      <A  HREF=/netacgi/nph-Parser?Sect1=PTO2&Sect2=HITOFF&u=%2Fnetahtml%2FPTO%2Fsearch-adv.htm&r=10&p=1&f=G&l=50&d=PTXT&S1=*a&OS=*a&RS=*a>mRNA cap analogs</A>
    </TD>
```

so I want my text box show the below

```
/netacgi/nph-Parser?Sect1=PTO2&Sect2=HITOFF&u=%2Fnetahtml%2FPTO%2Fsearch-adv.htm&r=10&p=1&f=G&l=50&d=PTXT&S1=*a&OS=*a&RS=*a

8,519,110

mRNA cap analogs
```

the above html tag is repeated to have more table rows, and want to get all of them, I have read that we can use the "GetAttribute" to get the html element, but I want to extract a specific parts as mentioned above.

Comment: You may want to look into HtmlAgilityPack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a routine I have been using to extract data from HTML tables
(Sorry to not credit the original author, I found this code and don't know where it came from). It parses HTML in a string for tables and load the cells into a dataset.

```
    Public Shared Function ConvertHtmlTablesToDataSet(html As String) As DataSet
    Dim dt As DataTable
    Dim ds As New DataSet()
    dt = New DataTable()
    Dim tableExpression As String = "<table[^>]*>(.*?)</table>"
    Dim headerExpression As String = "<th[^>]*>(.*?)</th>"
    Dim rowExpression As String = "<tr[^>]*>(.*?)</tr>"
    Dim columnExpression As String = "<td[^>]*>(.*?)</td>"
    Dim headersExist As Boolean = False
    Dim iCurrentColumn As Integer = 0
    Dim iCurrentRow As Integer = 0

    Dim tables As MatchCollection = Regex.Matches(html, tableExpression, RegexOptions.Singleline Or RegexOptions.Multiline Or RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)


    For Each table As Match In tables
        iCurrentRow = 0
        headersExist = False
        dt = New DataTable()

        If table.Value.Contains("<th") Then
            headersExist = True

            Dim headers As MatchCollection = Regex.Matches(table.Value, headerExpression, RegexOptions.Singleline Or RegexOptions.Multiline Or RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)

            For Each header As Match In headers
                dt.Columns.Add(header.Groups(1).ToString())
            Next
        Else

            Dim myvar2222 As Integer = Regex.Matches(Regex.Matches(Regex.Matches(table.Value, tableExpression, RegexOptions.Singleline Or RegexOptions.Multiline Or RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)(0).ToString(), rowExpression, RegexOptions.Singleline Or RegexOptions.Multiline Or RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)(0).ToString(), columnExpression, RegexOptions.Singleline Or RegexOptions.Multiline Or RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Count

            For iColumns As Integer = 1 To myvar2222
                dt.Columns.Add("Column " + System.Convert.ToString(iColumns))

            Next
        End If

        Dim rows As MatchCollection = Regex.Matches(table.Value, rowExpression, RegexOptions.Singleline Or RegexOptions.Multiline Or RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
        Try

            For Each row As Match In rows
                If Not ((iCurrentRow = 0) And headersExist) Then
                    Dim dr As DataRow = dt.NewRow()
                    iCurrentColumn = 0

                    Dim columns As MatchCollection = Regex.Matches(row.Value, columnExpression, RegexOptions.Singleline Or RegexOptions.Multiline Or RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)

                    For Each column As Match In columns
                        dr(iCurrentColumn) = column.Groups(1).ToString()
                        iCurrentColumn += 1
                        If iCurrentColumn = dt.Columns.Count Then Exit For
                    Next

                    dt.Rows.Add(dr)
                End If
                iCurrentRow += 1
            Next

            ds.Tables.Add(dt)
        Catch ex As Exception
            Stop
        End Try
    Next

    Return ds
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

Without understanding why you want to do this, it's a bit hard to give you a good solution.

I will provide two options:

1) VB.NET - it's not clear how you are setting your attributes in your HTML. You should be able to do something like (note: this is from my memory of VB.net and handcoded here, not using VS.net):

**HTML View:**

```
<asp:HyperLink id="FirstLink" runat="server" />
...
```

**Codebehind**

```
FirstLink.NavigateUrl = yourUrlVariableHere
...
YourInputBox.Text = String.Concat(yourUrlVariableHere, yourOtherVariablesHere ...)
```

2) jQuery -

Essentially you want to get your attributes and then display them:

```
$(function(){
    var anchor1 = $("#firstAnchor").attr("href");
    var imageSrc = $("#my-image").attr("src");

    $("#my-display").html(anchor1+ "<br/>" + imageSrc );
});
```

Full sample [here](http://jsfiddle.net/h296e/)